# Flask-Restx: Set default route from Swagger?

Tags: flask, swagger, flask-restx

I have some database services that take a bit of time to run before my swagger interface is loaded. So, I want to load an HTML page with the information & then redirect it to the swagger documentation.

How can I add a default route that I can load with flask-restx?

The code would do something along the lines of

```
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/start")
def hello():
    return render_template("loading_spinner.html")


api = Api(
    app,
    version="1.0",
    title="Python API",
    description="API with Flask-RestX",
)

nsHealthCheck = api.namespace(
    "api/v1/healthcheck", description="Health check for the API"
)
```

In this example, I want to load `/start` before the swagger interface. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I hope I get your q right.

After my understanding the solution could be:

- a UI problem
- together with a Flask problem

1. My first try
   What I would do if I have to make something like this is definitely just Geeks wrote here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-show-page-loading-div-until-the-page-has-finished-loading/
   Combining this html load icon with the 'turbo-flask' package.

The idea is simply that while a user is waiting to load a page (more precisely until you can load the swagger docs, the html loader does its thing, and then bummm, here you go with the dynamic update as is written here: https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/dynamically-update-your-flask-web-pages-using-turbo-flask

This is the 3pp: https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/turbo-flask
So the most interesting part is here:

```
import time

# ...

def update_load():
    with app.app_context():
        while True:
            time.sleep(5)
            turbo.push(turbo.replace(render_template('loadavg.html'), 'load'))
```

And then you can tweak the default API doc render as it says: https://flask-restx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/swagger.html#customization

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restx import Api, apidoc

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

@api.documentation
def custom_ui():
    return apidoc.ui_for(api)
```

You can even modify the url for the swagger of course...

2. If the first one looks devastating, then:

Another solution could be by modifying the swagger load, insert there a SSE type of load, I mean this one: https://github.com/singingwolfboy/flask-sse
Until a moment you send where are your job status, and then simply replace the page finally.

It could be, that I over complicated this simple problem. In this case, im waiting on more elegant solutions.